How to get Shortcut to process a set of images in a folder without it pausing to ask me to manually click on each image during the shortcut?
I have multiple AppleTVs. I would like to have a slideshow running photos of the past year's adventures and display the location at the bottom left and the date taken at the bottom right corner of each image. Yes, this simple feature should be something that Apple's own slide shows and AppleTV could do on their own without my intervention - but Apple has dropped the ball on much of their software.... I digress.
I have written a Shortcut to take a folder of my favorite photos exported from Photos (which contains the necessary EXIF data), overlay the necessary info, and then save each as a new image in a new folder. I've managed to get this to work fine - with one exception. The test folder has 10 images in it,  whereas, in the real world, the actual folder will hold ~1000 images. The Shortcut runs and pauses, asking me to click on each image in the folder via a thumbnail the shortcut displays; after I've clicked 10 times, the processed images all appear in my target folder, and the text overlays looks great.
How do I edit the Shortcut, or covert it to an automation, or any other reasonable approach so that I can just point it to a folder of 2000 photos and have it do its thing without bothering me? I fear this might be a limitation of the "Overlay text" action in Shortcuts, but I am not sure.
Below is a copy of the Shortcut.
Edit: Here is link to the Shortcut: https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/326e58e576b74578bb7d954693301e77


Please could you [edit] in an iCloud link to the shortcut?

Does it do the same thing if, instead of extracting them from a folder, you select the individual photos?

@ red_menace, I thought I could make a Shortcut that one could drag a set of files too (like one could do with an Automator app, but I couldn't figure out how to do this with a Shortcut. I also tried having the "input" be to pick photos, rather than open a folder, but that also results in me having to pick 100s or 1000s of photos individually.

The solution was to change "Repeat with each time in" pointing to "Files" to instead be "Repeat with each item in" pointing to "Repeat Item" so that each interaction of the overlay isn't asking to pick files.
Working Shortcut is:

and can be downloaded from here:
https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/d51590914eba4a1daf33cfa29e866396

Thank you for posting an answer. You write The solution was to change "Repeat with each time in" pointing to "Files" to instead be "Repeat with each item in" pointing to "Repeat Item" but in the Shortcut you provide I see that "Repeat with each time in" still points to "Files". Is the linked Shortcut not yet updated?
